# Accessing DbContext outside of the projet

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net

I have a Data Access Class Library working with EF.

**The DbContext**

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext() : base("name=ModelContainer")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Customer> Customer { get; set; }
}
```

I can access the DbContext inside my DAL project but I can't access the context from another projet.

**From my ASP MVC project**

```
MyDbContext ctx = new MyDbContext();
ctx.Customer.* //<-- I don't have access to any method or property
```

Comment: Based on your property name that should be `ctx.Customer` of type `Client`.

Comment: You really should expose an API to your data instead of directly exposing your DbContext.

Comment: @Crowcoder I'll add a business layer between the DAL and the WebApp

Comment: @Fabulous I've edited my post, I made a mistake when I wrote my post.

Comment: Did you declare your Customer entity as public? If intellisense picked up MyDbContext without issue, my first guess was that your Customer class wasn't scoped as public. The default class scope is internal.  Though this would have likely been accompanied by build errors that the Customer DbSet was more visible than the Customer class. If the Customer's properties were declared internal then other assemblies wouldn't see those even if the Customer class was public. (Maybe another dev was making a point that entities shouldn't be used outside of DAL.)